# Lost our IOHK delegation for SPO

Tags: spo

So we run plebpool.com [PLBPL]. We received IOHK delegation and our pool has gone from strength to strength. We are south african based and ran the Johannesburg leg of the cardano world summit. We have been supporting a local organisation called https://www.lifechangersa.org/ which helps homeless people in South Africa. We recently lost our delegation of 3.2M ADA which moved to another pool that already had 2.4M ADA staked. We know this is fair and within any ones rights to move delegations we just want to know, did we do something wrong? It would have been nice for a heads up of some kind as now we have to goto our charity and say we can help nearly as much as before, and why did the delegation move to a pool that seemigly already has established itself as a successful SPO. We were helped out but the move doesnt make too much sense, just looking for some answers as we are left a little perplexed. Thanks community!

Answer (score 5):

IOG as well as the Cardano Foundation run a process for the so called delegation support. Every ~3 months, they choose new pools to delegate to. You didn't do anything wrong, my friend. The whale just moves on, as they always do. :)

As for IOG they usually open up an online form to apply for their delegation and was announced in Sept: https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/09/01/cardano-stake-pool-operator-delegation-a-new-round/

IOG and CF are not aligned in how they choose pools. You can read the latest statement about the CF delegation here: https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-foundation-announces-its-delegation-methodology-closed/41090

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Delegation has rotated. This is a normal behaviour form IOG, as Delegation is not meant to stay forever to one pool.

But the lucky thing is that you can reapply for another round next time the window open up!

Answer (score 0):

you were so lucky that you had it at least once.
some other pools, like our TTS17 is waiting

we will try again next time.
have a nice Cardano Journey mate.
TTS17